# how to add image ol.control.ZoomToExtent in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

In ol.control.ZoomToExtent,Openlayers3 use 'E' character for view (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/navigation-controls.html).
But i want to add image.How to do this ?

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up the control you can pass it several options, one of those is **label** [(ZoomToExtent Documentation)](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.control.ZoomToExtent.html).

Set that **label** to '' and set a **className** to a particular style, style the element in CSS, adding an image as required.

Comment: can you send me sample?

Comment: Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pd5aboa/2/).  It makes the button an image.

Comment: No problem.  If that works for you, don't forget to Mark the question as answered, so others can find the solution.  Good luck

Comment: please check next question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643984/why-doesnt-show-feature-on-map