# why doesn't show feature on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

this is fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ismayil1993/qk035jjf/).Feature doesn't show on map when it has been like this code :

```
 var featureVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: featureClusterSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});
```

But i change source - featureClusterSource to featureVectorSource.it works well but in this time i don't get feature when i click feature on map .

```
 var featureVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: featureVectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});
```

How do I show feature on map with featureClusterSource?

Comment: With featureVectorSource as the source, your code worked for me. I even got the click event.

Comment: yes it works with featureVectorSource .but it doesn't work with featureClusterSource

Comment: Is there a reason you can't proceed with vector source?

Comment: yeah because when i click on features intersect i got only one feature .it doesn't true.i must get both feature

Comment: For that, you'll have to change forEachFeatureAtPixel method. According to your code, that method returns the feature soon after it detects a feature. so whatever feature is on top will be returned.

Comment: How do I do this? How do I get features when i click feaures intersect?

Comment: see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/itsyahani/y35orrn2/) fiddle

Comment: thank you very very much :)

Comment: if you have facebook ,please send friend request .https://www.facebook.com/aqazadaismayil

Comment: Glad I could help. :) I'll add this as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i change source - featureClusterSource to featureVectorSource.it works well but in this time i don't get feature when i click feature on map .

When clicked on features which are intersecting, change forEachFeatureAtPixel method to add them to an array.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/itsyahani/y35orrn2/)'s a working fiddle

```
    map.on("singleclick", singleClickCB);
    function singleClickCB(event) {
        var features = [];
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
          features.push(feature);
        });
        if (features) {
           var i;
           for (i = 0; i < features.length; ++i) {
              alert(features[i].get('title'));
            }
         }
   } ;
```

Comment: can you check this questoin?
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176027/why-dont-work-turf-intersect-with-this-coordinates